# Reading IDML coordinate hell

Tags: xml, adobe, coordinates, coordinate-transformation, idml

I am trying to parse an IDML spread containing a few rectangles, 8 in total.
The rectangles are copy-pasted from one original rectangle, rotated and positioned on the spread.

In the IDML file, all the rectangles appear to have the same origin points, with only varying tranformation per element. I am trying to figure out how to convert that whole nested nightmare into a neat set of center-point oriented coordinates and dimensions.

Below is the spread XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<idPkg:Spread xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="11.0">
<Spread Self="ud7" FlattenerOverride="Default" AllowPageShuffle="true" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 0 2060.784" ShowMasterItems="true" PageCount="2" BindingLocation="1" PageTransitionType="None" PageTransitionDirection="NotApplicable" PageTransitionDuration="Medium">
    <FlattenerPreference LineArtAndTextResolution="300" GradientAndMeshResolution="150" ClipComplexRegions="false" ConvertAllStrokesToOutlines="false" ConvertAllTextToOutlines="false">
        <Properties>
            <RasterVectorBalance type="double">50</RasterVectorBalance>
        </Properties>
    </FlattenerPreference>
    <Page Self="u10f" AppliedAlternateLayout="ucd" LayoutRule="UseMaster" SnapshotBlendingMode="IgnoreLayoutSnapshots" OptionalPage="false" GeometricBounds="0 0 850.392 850.392" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 -850.392 -425.196" Name="4" AppliedTrapPreset="TrapPreset/$ID/kDefaultTrapStyleName" OverrideList="" AppliedMaster="uce" MasterPageTransform="1 0 0 1 238.39200000000002 29.196000000000023" TabOrder="" GridStartingPoint="TopOutside" UseMasterGrid="false">
        <Properties>
            <Descriptor type="list">
                <ListItem type="string"></ListItem>
                <ListItem type="enumeration">Arabic</ListItem>
                <ListItem type="boolean">true</ListItem>
                <ListItem type="boolean">false</ListItem>
                <ListItem type="long">4</ListItem>
                <ListItem type="string"></ListItem>
            </Descriptor>
            <PageColor type="enumeration">UseMasterColor</PageColor>
        </Properties>
        <MarginPreference ColumnCount="1" ColumnGutter="12" Top="8.5032" Bottom="8.5032" Left="8.5032" Right="8.5032" ColumnDirection="Horizontal" ColumnsPositions="0 833.3856000000001" />
        <GridDataInformation FontStyle="Regular" PointSize="12" CharacterAki="0" LineAki="9" HorizontalScale="100" VerticalScale="100" LineAlignment="LeftOrTopLineJustify" GridAlignment="AlignEmCenter" CharacterAlignment="AlignEmCenter">
            <Properties>
                <AppliedFont type="string">Minion Pro</AppliedFont>
            </Properties>
        </GridDataInformation>
    </Page>
    <Page Self="u110" AppliedAlternateLayout="ucd" LayoutRule="UseMaster" SnapshotBlendingMode="IgnoreLayoutSnapshots" OptionalPage="false" GeometricBounds="0 0 850.392 850.392" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 0 -425.196" Name="5" AppliedTrapPreset="TrapPreset/$ID/kDefaultTrapStyleName" OverrideList="" AppliedMaster="uce" MasterPageTransform="1 0 0 1 0 29.196000000000023" TabOrder="" GridStartingPoint="TopOutside" UseMasterGrid="false">
        <Properties>
            <Descriptor type="list">
                <ListItem type="string"></ListItem>
                <ListItem type="enumeration">Arabic</ListItem>
                <ListItem type="boolean">true</ListItem>
                <ListItem type="boolean">false</ListItem>
                <ListItem type="long">5</ListItem>
                <ListItem type="string"></ListItem>
            </Descriptor>
            <PageColor type="enumeration">UseMasterColor</PageColor>
        </Properties>
        <MarginPreference ColumnCount="1" ColumnGutter="12" Top="8.5032" Bottom="8.5032" Left="8.5032" Right="8.5032" ColumnDirection="Horizontal" ColumnsPositions="0 833.3856000000001" />
        <GridDataInformation FontStyle="Regular" PointSize="12" CharacterAki="0" LineAki="9" HorizontalScale="100" VerticalScale="100" LineAlignment="LeftOrTopLineJustify" GridAlignment="AlignEmCenter" CharacterAlignment="AlignEmCenter">
            <Properties>
                <AppliedFont type="string">Minion Pro</AppliedFont>
            </Properties>
        </GridDataInformation>
    </Page>
    <Rectangle Self="u209" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="u135" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 135.1960000000007 -2051.9999999999995">
        <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
                <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                    <PathPointArray>
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 1702.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 1702.5" RightDirection="-609.892 1702.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 2401.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 2401.5" RightDirection="-609.892 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" />
                    </PathPointArray>
                </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Properties>
        <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
            <Properties>
                <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
            </Properties>
        </TextWrapPreference>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <FrameFittingOption AutoFit="false" LeftCrop="0" TopCrop="0" RightCrop="0" BottomCrop="0" FittingOnEmptyFrame="None" FittingAlignment="CenterAnchor" />
        <ObjectExportOption EpubType="$ID/" SizeType="DefaultSize" CustomSize="$ID/" PreserveAppearanceFromLayout="PreserveAppearanceDefault" AltTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" ActualTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" CustomAltText="$ID/" CustomActualText="$ID/" ApplyTagType="TagFromStructure" ImageConversionType="JPEG" ImageExportResolution="Ppi300" GIFOptionsPalette="AdaptivePalette" GIFOptionsInterlaced="true" JPEGOptionsQuality="High" JPEGOptionsFormat="BaselineEncoding" ImageAlignment="AlignLeft" ImageSpaceBefore="0" ImageSpaceAfter="0" UseImagePageBreak="false" ImagePageBreak="PageBreakBefore" CustomImageAlignment="false" SpaceUnit="CssPixel" CustomLayout="false" CustomLayoutType="AlignmentAndSpacing">
            <Properties>
                <AltMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
                <ActualMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
            </Properties>
        </ObjectExportOption>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Self="u20a" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="u135" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865476 0.7071067811865476 0.7071067811865476 -1479.9221316721032 -1847.240098317487">
        <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
                <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                    <PathPointArray>
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 1702.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 1702.5" RightDirection="-609.892 1702.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 2401.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 2401.5" RightDirection="-609.892 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" />
                    </PathPointArray>
                </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Properties>
        <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
            <Properties>
                <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
            </Properties>
        </TextWrapPreference>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <FrameFittingOption AutoFit="false" LeftCrop="0" TopCrop="0" RightCrop="0" BottomCrop="0" FittingOnEmptyFrame="None" FittingAlignment="CenterAnchor" />
        <ObjectExportOption EpubType="$ID/" SizeType="DefaultSize" CustomSize="$ID/" PreserveAppearanceFromLayout="PreserveAppearanceDefault" AltTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" ActualTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" CustomAltText="$ID/" CustomActualText="$ID/" ApplyTagType="TagFromStructure" ImageConversionType="JPEG" ImageExportResolution="Ppi300" GIFOptionsPalette="AdaptivePalette" GIFOptionsInterlaced="true" JPEGOptionsQuality="High" JPEGOptionsFormat="BaselineEncoding" ImageAlignment="AlignLeft" ImageSpaceBefore="0" ImageSpaceAfter="0" UseImagePageBreak="false" ImagePageBreak="PageBreakBefore" CustomImageAlignment="false" SpaceUnit="CssPixel" CustomLayout="false" CustomLayoutType="AlignmentAndSpacing">
            <Properties>
                <AltMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
                <ActualMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
            </Properties>
        </ObjectExportOption>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Self="u20b" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="u135" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="0 -1 1 0 -2477.196 -560.392">
        <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
                <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                    <PathPointArray>
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 1702.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 1702.5" RightDirection="-609.892 1702.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 2401.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 2401.5" RightDirection="-609.892 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" />
                    </PathPointArray>
                </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Properties>
        <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
            <Properties>
                <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
            </Properties>
        </TextWrapPreference>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <FrameFittingOption AutoFit="false" LeftCrop="0" TopCrop="0" RightCrop="0" BottomCrop="0" FittingOnEmptyFrame="None" FittingAlignment="CenterAnchor" />
        <ObjectExportOption EpubType="$ID/" SizeType="DefaultSize" CustomSize="$ID/" PreserveAppearanceFromLayout="PreserveAppearanceDefault" AltTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" ActualTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" CustomAltText="$ID/" CustomActualText="$ID/" ApplyTagType="TagFromStructure" ImageConversionType="JPEG" ImageExportResolution="Ppi300" GIFOptionsPalette="AdaptivePalette" GIFOptionsInterlaced="true" JPEGOptionsQuality="High" JPEGOptionsFormat="BaselineEncoding" ImageAlignment="AlignLeft" ImageSpaceBefore="0" ImageSpaceAfter="0" UseImagePageBreak="false" ImagePageBreak="PageBreakBefore" CustomImageAlignment="false" SpaceUnit="CssPixel" CustomLayout="false" CustomLayoutType="AlignmentAndSpacing">
            <Properties>
                <AltMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
                <ActualMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
            </Properties>
        </ObjectExportOption>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Self="u20c" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="u135" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="-0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865476 0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865476 -2272.4360983174865 1054.7261316721044">
        <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
                <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                    <PathPointArray>
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 1702.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 1702.5" RightDirection="-609.892 1702.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 2401.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 2401.5" RightDirection="-609.892 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" />
                    </PathPointArray>
                </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Properties>
        <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
            <Properties>
                <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
            </Properties>
        </TextWrapPreference>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <FrameFittingOption AutoFit="false" LeftCrop="0" TopCrop="0" RightCrop="0" BottomCrop="0" FittingOnEmptyFrame="None" FittingAlignment="CenterAnchor" />
        <ObjectExportOption EpubType="$ID/" SizeType="DefaultSize" CustomSize="$ID/" PreserveAppearanceFromLayout="PreserveAppearanceDefault" AltTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" ActualTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" CustomAltText="$ID/" CustomActualText="$ID/" ApplyTagType="TagFromStructure" ImageConversionType="JPEG" ImageExportResolution="Ppi300" GIFOptionsPalette="AdaptivePalette" GIFOptionsInterlaced="true" JPEGOptionsQuality="High" JPEGOptionsFormat="BaselineEncoding" ImageAlignment="AlignLeft" ImageSpaceBefore="0" ImageSpaceAfter="0" UseImagePageBreak="false" ImagePageBreak="PageBreakBefore" CustomImageAlignment="false" SpaceUnit="CssPixel" CustomLayout="false" CustomLayoutType="AlignmentAndSpacing">
            <Properties>
                <AltMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
                <ActualMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
            </Properties>
        </ObjectExportOption>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Self="u20d" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="u135" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 985.5880000000008 -2051.9999999999995">
        <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
                <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                    <PathPointArray>
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 1702.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 1702.5" RightDirection="-609.892 1702.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 2401.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 2401.5" RightDirection="-609.892 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" />
                    </PathPointArray>
                </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Properties>
        <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
            <Properties>
                <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
            </Properties>
        </TextWrapPreference>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <FrameFittingOption AutoFit="false" LeftCrop="0" TopCrop="0" RightCrop="0" BottomCrop="0" FittingOnEmptyFrame="None" FittingAlignment="CenterAnchor" />
        <ObjectExportOption EpubType="$ID/" SizeType="DefaultSize" CustomSize="$ID/" PreserveAppearanceFromLayout="PreserveAppearanceDefault" AltTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" ActualTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" CustomAltText="$ID/" CustomActualText="$ID/" ApplyTagType="TagFromStructure" ImageConversionType="JPEG" ImageExportResolution="Ppi300" GIFOptionsPalette="AdaptivePalette" GIFOptionsInterlaced="true" JPEGOptionsQuality="High" JPEGOptionsFormat="BaselineEncoding" ImageAlignment="AlignLeft" ImageSpaceBefore="0" ImageSpaceAfter="0" UseImagePageBreak="false" ImagePageBreak="PageBreakBefore" CustomImageAlignment="false" SpaceUnit="CssPixel" CustomLayout="false" CustomLayoutType="AlignmentAndSpacing">
            <Properties>
                <AltMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
                <ActualMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
            </Properties>
        </ObjectExportOption>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Self="u20e" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="u135" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865476 0.7071067811865476 0.7071067811865476 -629.5301316721034 -1847.2400983174869">
        <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
                <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                    <PathPointArray>
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 1702.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 1702.5" RightDirection="-609.892 1702.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 2401.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 2401.5" RightDirection="-609.892 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" />
                    </PathPointArray>
                </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Properties>
        <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
            <Properties>
                <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
            </Properties>
        </TextWrapPreference>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <FrameFittingOption AutoFit="false" LeftCrop="0" TopCrop="0" RightCrop="0" BottomCrop="0" FittingOnEmptyFrame="None" FittingAlignment="CenterAnchor" />
        <ObjectExportOption EpubType="$ID/" SizeType="DefaultSize" CustomSize="$ID/" PreserveAppearanceFromLayout="PreserveAppearanceDefault" AltTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" ActualTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" CustomAltText="$ID/" CustomActualText="$ID/" ApplyTagType="TagFromStructure" ImageConversionType="JPEG" ImageExportResolution="Ppi300" GIFOptionsPalette="AdaptivePalette" GIFOptionsInterlaced="true" JPEGOptionsQuality="High" JPEGOptionsFormat="BaselineEncoding" ImageAlignment="AlignLeft" ImageSpaceBefore="0" ImageSpaceAfter="0" UseImagePageBreak="false" ImagePageBreak="PageBreakBefore" CustomImageAlignment="false" SpaceUnit="CssPixel" CustomLayout="false" CustomLayoutType="AlignmentAndSpacing">
            <Properties>
                <AltMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
                <ActualMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
            </Properties>
        </ObjectExportOption>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Self="u20f" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="u135" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="0 -1 1 0 -1626.804 -560.392">
        <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
                <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                    <PathPointArray>
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 1702.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 1702.5" RightDirection="-609.892 1702.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 2401.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 2401.5" RightDirection="-609.892 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" />
                    </PathPointArray>
                </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Properties>
        <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
            <Properties>
                <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
            </Properties>
        </TextWrapPreference>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <FrameFittingOption AutoFit="false" LeftCrop="0" TopCrop="0" RightCrop="0" BottomCrop="0" FittingOnEmptyFrame="None" FittingAlignment="CenterAnchor" />
        <ObjectExportOption EpubType="$ID/" SizeType="DefaultSize" CustomSize="$ID/" PreserveAppearanceFromLayout="PreserveAppearanceDefault" AltTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" ActualTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" CustomAltText="$ID/" CustomActualText="$ID/" ApplyTagType="TagFromStructure" ImageConversionType="JPEG" ImageExportResolution="Ppi300" GIFOptionsPalette="AdaptivePalette" GIFOptionsInterlaced="true" JPEGOptionsQuality="High" JPEGOptionsFormat="BaselineEncoding" ImageAlignment="AlignLeft" ImageSpaceBefore="0" ImageSpaceAfter="0" UseImagePageBreak="false" ImagePageBreak="PageBreakBefore" CustomImageAlignment="false" SpaceUnit="CssPixel" CustomLayout="false" CustomLayoutType="AlignmentAndSpacing">
            <Properties>
                <AltMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
                <ActualMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
            </Properties>
        </ObjectExportOption>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Self="u210" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="u135" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="-0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865476 0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865476 -1422.0440983174867 1054.726131672103">
        <Properties>
            <PathGeometry>
                <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                    <PathPointArray>
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 1702.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 1702.5" RightDirection="-609.892 1702.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-609.892 2401.5" LeftDirection="-609.892 2401.5" RightDirection="-609.892 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 2401.5" />
                        <PathPointType Anchor="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" LeftDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" RightDirection="-510.89200000000005 1702.5" />
                    </PathPointArray>
                </GeometryPathType>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Properties>
        <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
            <Properties>
                <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
            </Properties>
        </TextWrapPreference>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <FrameFittingOption AutoFit="false" LeftCrop="0" TopCrop="0" RightCrop="0" BottomCrop="0" FittingOnEmptyFrame="None" FittingAlignment="CenterAnchor" />
        <ObjectExportOption EpubType="$ID/" SizeType="DefaultSize" CustomSize="$ID/" PreserveAppearanceFromLayout="PreserveAppearanceDefault" AltTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" ActualTextSourceType="SourceXMLStructure" CustomAltText="$ID/" CustomActualText="$ID/" ApplyTagType="TagFromStructure" ImageConversionType="JPEG" ImageExportResolution="Ppi300" GIFOptionsPalette="AdaptivePalette" GIFOptionsInterlaced="true" JPEGOptionsQuality="High" JPEGOptionsFormat="BaselineEncoding" ImageAlignment="AlignLeft" ImageSpaceBefore="0" ImageSpaceAfter="0" UseImagePageBreak="false" ImagePageBreak="PageBreakBefore" CustomImageAlignment="false" SpaceUnit="CssPixel" CustomLayout="false" CustomLayoutType="AlignmentAndSpacing">
            <Properties>
                <AltMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
                <ActualMetadataProperty NamespacePrefix="$ID/" PropertyPath="$ID/" />
            </Properties>
        </ObjectExportOption>
    </Rectangle>
</Spread>
</idPkg:Spread>
```

In InDesign it looks like this:
[image]
Could anyone please please explain how to get two sets of 4 identical center-point coordinates from all this mess?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the PathPointTypes in the PathPointArray express object coordinates in its inner coordinate space (transformations independant). The attribute ItemTransform="-0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865476 0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865476 -1422.0440983174867 1054.726131672103" would be then used to affect the object geometry on a upper layer.
So the bad news here is that you would have to master the transformation matrices computation to get the final coordinates of the page item in the spread coordinates given that the spread has not been rotated/skewed neither.
Otherwise you would have a second set of computations to achieve.

Comment: The spreads are not modified (I already do compensation for the spread offset, since it's a multiple-spread document). The problem I'm facing here IS the actual computation - I tried applying the transformation matrix to the objects, but all the rotated ones appear to be "prancing" around the page wildly. I don't have a problem with multiple computation sets, provided they do the job. I just can't wrap my mind around HOW to do the computation correctly.